# Don't throw it to me

Tags: grammar

He took his Lego toys and threw to me.

> "Don't throw me."
>
> "Don't throw it to me."

Do I need to say it in complete sentence as the second one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With English, it is often not enough to learn the meaning of individual verbs.  You also have to learn the difference in meaning between verbs paired with various prepostions.

For example, all of the following have different meanings:

> *Throw to*
>
> *Throw at*
>
> *Throw in*
>
> *Throw out*
>
> *Throw over*

plus a few others.

"To throw (something) **to** (someone)" means to toss something through the air, to someone, with the intention that they should *catch it*.

> I pulled an apple off the tree and **threw it to** my brother below.

In the situation you describe, you should use "to throw (something) **at** (someone)".  This means to hurl something, with some force, toward someone with the intention of hitting them and possibly hurting them.

> The pitcher intentionally **threw the ball at** the batter, forcing him to dodge away from the plate.
>
> Don't **throw your toys at** me!

Answer (score 2):

**"Throw it to me."** implies that he is throwing it in order for you to catch it.

**"Throw it at me"** means that he is probably trying to hit you with the lego.

**"Don't throw it to me"** can be said on its own because there is a **subject** (you is implied) and a **verb** (throw)